# Add additional data to iBeacon transmitter

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon

i tried to simulate transmitting ibeacon using alt beacon lib

```
mBeaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(this, new AltBeaconParser());
Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
    .setId1("2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6")
    .setId2("1")
    .setId3("2")
    .setManufacturer(0x0000) // Choose a number of 0x00ff or less as some devices cannot detect beacons with a manufacturer code > 0x00ff
    .setTxPower(-59)
    .setDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[]{238L}))
    .build();
```

What's the right way to send some kind of `id` in `Int` or `Long` type?

Answer (score 0):

What you show is the correct way to send a single byte with value 238 as an extra data field.

The AltBeacon format only supports adding a single byte of data, because that is all that fits in the maximum length of the Bluetooth LE advertising packet, given the other identifiers and fields in the AltBeacon specification.

You are welcome to encode data in the identifier fields like ID3, which gives you more bytes to work with.

Comment: thanks for response, for now it's just a test project to check, how the different format works and how to send a data via these format.
In real case i need to fetch data from manufactured data as array of bytes and have possibility to test it via your test project.
Does - `setManufacturer` the right thing to do it?

Comment: and i have to send the real `id` via manufacturer field, like `1231231238`

Comment: the manufacturer id field is only two bytes, so if you use that be sure your value fits.

Comment: so, if i have a different type (layout) of beacon, (no altbeacon, ibeacon or eddyson), i should write my own parser to build a beacon object, am i right?

Comment: or the built-in parser can parse any layout i pass